# Pass @Value values to Config class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a config class in which I'm setting the `JavaMailSenderImpl` properties, but I want to not set the values in the `@Bean` and just to set them to get via methods (ex:`mailSender.setPort(ClassImpl.getPort());`). Below is the code, and I tried to pass the values via getters, but I get the npe.

```
//properties.file
mail.host=the_host
mail.port=123
mail.username=the_username
mail.password=the_password
```

```
// ClassInterface has only one sendMail method
@Component
public class ClassImpl implements ClassInterface{
    @Value("${mail.host}")
    public String host;

    @Value("${mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${mail.password}")
    private String password;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String sender, String receiver, String subject, String content) {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(sender);
        message.setTo(receiver);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);

        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(host_here);
        mailSender.setPort(port_here);
        mailSender.setUsername(user_here);
        mailSender.setPassword(pwd_here);
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

EDIT

tried to make this getHost `static` and pass the method like this:

```
mailSender.setHost(ClassImpl.getHost()); 
// but I get the 'refused  to connect' and it sets the value to 'localhost'
// and not to the value @Value host I need from properties.file
```

Comment: The NPE you get would be interesting, it's probably because you use something wrong since this should in theory work fine. Also where is ClassImpl or ClassInterface used? You should be doing something like `@Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderService(ClassInterface if) { ... mailSender.setHost(if.getHost())` - edit: spring does not inject into static field. And since you have a circular thing between the class if and the sender, maybe split ClassInterface into config and actual sender so that you end up with sender < javamail < config instead of your circle.

Comment: @zapl yes, it worked, i'll add this as correct sollution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zapl commented, I added ClassImpl in @Bean parameter and it works fine.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderService(ClassImpl ci) {
....
```